# how to make progress bar work with functions in button event

Tags: c#, events, button, timer, progress-bar

i am new in C# so please be patient with me .

i want to make progress bar work with any functions i make in my program

i have class to check if INTERNET available and the connection of database status

and i have "**progressBar1**" , style is "**Marquee**"

i just want to indicate that there is a process work "Function" in the program and i don't need to have step or timer to increment it

just make the progress work until the function finish its code and the functions will work in button event (**when i push button**)

this is my code

```
class checkInternet
{
    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

public bool checkInternetAvailable()
{
    int Desc;
    bool result = false;

    if (InternetGetConnectedState(out Desc, 0) == true)
    {
        try
        {
            dbConnection StartConn = new dbConnection();
            SqlConnection MyConnetion = StartConn.GetConnection();

            MyConnetion.Open();

            if (MyConnetion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                result = true;
            }

            MyConnetion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result = false;
            MessageBox.Show("The database connection does not available, May be because of this reasons: \n\n1- there is a new version of the program avalible. \n2- database has some maintenance. \n\n Please check later :)", "Conection status");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result = false;
        MessageBox.Show("No internet connection avalible , Please check later :) \nThanks.", "Conection status");
    }

    return result;
}
}
```

and this is what i have in my button event

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkInternet check = new checkInternet();

        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        do
        {
            progressBar1.PerformStep();

        } while (check.checkInternetAvailable());
    }
```

how can i implement that ?

thanks

Comment: Can you try using async await

Comment: how can i make it i will try anything to do it but how ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want user to see progressbar while your check connection task executes in background. checkInternetAvailable would be your background operation and I wouldn't suggest showing messages directly form it. Instead return a custom struct :

```
   public struct ConnectionCheckResult
   {
       public bool Success;
       public string Message;
   }
```

And this will be your button click event handler :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            //add code here to be executed on UI thread before connection check
            Task.Run(new Action(() => 
            {
                //Task.Run this code on the thread pool instead of your UI thread. So your code is checking connection while progress bar is still rendering
                ConnectionCheckResult res = new checkInternet().checkInternetAvailable();
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => 
                {
                    //this.Invoke executes following delegate on UI thread. All UI changes - like progressBar1.Visible = false; need to be made in UI thread.
                    //add code here to be executed on the UI thread after connection check.
                    progressBar1.Visible = false;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(res.Message))
                        MessageBox.Show(res.Message);

                }));

            }));
            //add code to be executed on UI thread at the same time as connection check
        }
```

I know multi-threading is difficult to wrap your head around at first, here's [good tutorial with code samples](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/748815/WinForms-and-TPL-Achieving-quick-Multitasking-and).

Also when your progressbar style is Marquee you don't need to call PerformStep. It will just roll by itself.

EDIT: You should also modify checkInternetAvailable() like so :

```
public ConnectionCheckResult checkInternetAvailable()
{
    int Desc;
    ConnectionCheckResult result = new ConnectionCheckResult();

    if (InternetGetConnectedState(out Desc, 0) == true)
    {
        try
        {
            dbConnection StartConn = new dbConnection();
            SqlConnection MyConnetion = StartConn.GetConnection();

            MyConnetion.Open();

            if (MyConnetion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                result.Success = true;
            }

            MyConnetion.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            result.Success = false;
            result.Message = "The database connection does not available, May be because of this reasons: \n\n1- there is a new version of the program available. \n2- database has some maintenance. \n\n Please check later :)";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        result.Success = false;
        result.Message = "No internet connection available , Please check later :) \nThanks.";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `            checkInternet check = new checkInternet();            
            progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            progressBar1.Visible = true;          
            Task.Run(new Action(() =>
            {
                check.checkInternetAvailable();
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    progressBar1.Visible = false;
                    //MessageBox.Show("Finsh", "test");
                }));
            }));`

Comment: _Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'checkInernetAndDatabase.Form1.ConnectionCheckResult' checkInernetAndDatabase_

thats what is got by using your code but i edit it in small way if you see it will be fine 
this work good in first but in the second time it will be very fast but i think this is good

Comment: I added modified checkInternetAvailable() to the answer.